# How can I echo current url after query with symbols?

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo the current url using **php**. But it's not working because

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

I'm using **php 7.3**

```
<?php
$link = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$long_url = urlencode($link);
echo $long_url;
?>
```

The url path that I'm using:
 https://www.com/r/?https://mega.nz/#!link!pass 
but the result is:

> https%3A%2F%2Fmega.nz%2F

So the **query_string** command is not including after # symbol but when I delete the # symbol the code is working properly. 
Url path without # symbol:
 https://www.com/r/?https://mega.nz/!link!pass 

Result without # symbol:

> https%3A%2F%2Fmega.nz%2F%21link%21pass

Comment: Because you encode the url.

Comment: use `urldecode()` to get correct URL back

Comment: You cannot get the values of # variables because they are not sent to the server. If you want to get it you need a trick (from javascript or to duplicate it in standard GET variables)

Comment: It's not about the encode because even if I try to echo $link still it's not giving after # symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
$url_ = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" :  "http";

$url_ .= "://";

$url_ .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$url_ .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

echo $url_;
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. The result is https://www.com/r/?https://mega.nz/ but I want to echo the https://mega.nz/#!link!pass

Comment: Can you give me the URL which you are trying?

Comment: See my comment in the first post. It's not possible to pass the # variables

Comment: https://okitap.net/r/?https://mega.nz/#!z2BHWQqR!Q2aX74ti01h9XfX8mYURezFV-LcM1u-4CGuMnA4jSX4 this is the url that I'm trying.

Comment: You want to get https://mega.nz/#!z2BHWQqR!Q2aX74ti01h9XfX8mYURezFV-LcM1u-4CGuMnA4jSX4 this URL right?

Comment: Have you tried with Javascript or jQuery to get from URL?

Comment: Yes @VasantHun I want to het https://mega.nz/#!z2BHWQqR!Q2aX74ti01h9XfX8mYURezFV-LcM1u-4CGuMnA4jSX4.

Comment: And I didn't try jQuery or Javascript because I have no knowledge about these languages.

Comment: Are you okay with if I can get this URL using jQuery/JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

```
$current_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Comment: Not working. Everyone says that is not possible with standart http because even the server not including #. So that said I can do with javascript or Jquery tricks. Is there anyone can help me about that?